# Creating dictionary without the value part?

Tags: python

im reading a file with classes in it. I want to create a dictionary out of it with the classes as key so i can compare it to another more specific dictionary. i could do this as a list but going through each item in the list and comparing it with a dictionary seems tougher. Can a dictionary be built only of keys? and if it cant how can i just add a random value to it since i wont actually be using it?

Like

```
{Math 2415 : random or blank, 
 CSE 3314 : random or blank}
```

thanks

Comment: \n keeps on getting added in when doing edic{key} : [none]. why?

Answer (score 3):

You should use a set:

```
s = set(['Math 2415', 'CSE 3314'])
```

Test if a value is in the set:

```
'Math 2415' in s
```

Add another element to the set:

```
s.add('CS 1')
```

See [the python documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set) for other set operations.

Answer (score 2):

```
myDict = {'Math 2415' : None,  'CSE 3314' : None}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also look into using a `defaultdict`, with a default value corresponding to what you require. This would be the best way to implement random default values.

For example:

```
from random import randint
from collections import defaultdict

# a random value initializer
def randomval():
    return randint(1,100)

# your dictionary
mydict = defaultdict(randomval)

print mydict["Math 2415"] # initializes this key with 
                          # a random integer and prints it
```

Comment: @1_CR I'm not sure what you mean. The OP wants a dictionary with "random or default" values assigned for each of the keys in the dictionary. This job seems perfect for `defaultdict`.

Answer (score 0):

You should take [kalic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20206173/753731)'s suggestion and use a set

If you really need a dict with keys based on a list and values initialized to None

```
dict.fromkeys(['Math 2415', 'CSE 3314'])
{'Math 2415': None, 'CSE 3314': None}
```

Answer (score 0):

im not allowed to use a set. I tried what the first guy said in using None but \n kept on coming up. normally id just strip it away but none has no attribute strip. how do i get rid of the \n. heres what i wrote.

```
def createcompleteddic (cdic) :
    edic = {}
    for classs in fp :
        edic[classs]= [None.strip()]
    return edic

### Main ###
fp = open("completed.txt","r")
a = createcompleteddic(fp)
print a
```

Answer (score 0):

> going through each item in the list and comparing it with a dictionary

It's not tougher.

```
d = {'a':1, 'b':2}
l = ['a', 'b']
print [i in d for i in l]
```

You'll get

```
[True, False]
```

According to your code

```
def createcompleteddic (cdic) :
    edic = {}
    for classs in fp :
        edic[classs]= [None.strip()]
    return edic
```

Maybe you want this?

```
edic[classs.rstrip()] = None
```